# jenkins doesn't work with many cores and/or large memory

Tags: jenkins

I have started Jenkins on an aws m5.24xlarge instance with 96 vCPU and 384 GiB memory). When starting it, I find myself unable to access it. curl localhost:8080 hangs forever and gets no response. Also, there is no log output.

However, stopping the same instance, changing the instance type to m5.12xlarge (48 vCPU and 192 GiB memory) and running the same configuration again, works.

This is the same for running it via `java -jar jenkins.war`, by installing it via the `docker run jenkins/jenkins...` command or by installing it from a ubuntu repo.

Can any of you reproduce that issue? Is there a known maximum number of cores Jenkins can handle or a maximum memory size?

Or is there a starting flag that I can set so it works?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is the log output

```
Running from: /home/ubuntu/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:38 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFO: Logging initialized @236ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:38 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler setContextPath
WARNING: Empty contextPath
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: jetty-9.4.z-SNAPSHOT, build timestamp: 2017-11-21T21:27:37Z, git hash: 82b8fb23f757335bb3329d540ce37a2a2615f0a8
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor visitServlet
INFO: NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.DefaultSessionIdManager doStart
INFO: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:39 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HouseKeeper startScavenging
INFO: Scavenging every 660000ms
Jenkins home directory: /home/ubuntu/.jenkins found at: $user.home/.jenkins
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:40 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart
INFO: Started w.@644c78d4{/,file:///home/ubuntu/.jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/home/ubuntu/.jenkins/war}
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:40 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart
INFO: Started ServerConnector@355e34c7{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:40 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart
INFO: Started @1886ms
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:40 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v4.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:41 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:41 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:42 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:42 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:42 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:42 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:42 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Started Download metadata
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:43 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@46ce48b7: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Jul 06 13:55:43 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:43 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@46ce48b7]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@454a5ad5
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@454a5ad5: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:43 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@37a2b2a7: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Fri Jul 06 13:55:43 UTC 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:43 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@37a2b2a7]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@74441a6d
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@74441a6d: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:43 PM jenkins.install.SetupWizard init
INFO: 

*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************

Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

This may also be found at: /home/ubuntu/.jenkins/secrets/initialAdminPassword

*************************************************************
*************************************************************
*************************************************************

Jul 06, 2018 1:55:46 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData
INFO: Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:46 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite updateData
INFO: Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:46 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:46 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:46 PM hudson.model.DownloadService$Downloadable load
INFO: Obtained the updated data file for hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstaller
Jul 06, 2018 1:55:46 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
INFO: Finished Download metadata. 3,968 ms
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your problem. But I took a while to digest that you have the luxury of running jenkins on that m5.24xlarge instance. Simply WOW!

Comment: can you at least get the logs of jenkins? I'm sure not everyone can have access to m5.24xlarge get it reproduced.

Comment: This the very initial setup log. Im sure you know where to get the password and activitate jenkins. Btw, this log doesn't show any problems of hanging

Comment: thanks @VighneshPai . Yes, I know where to get from that log. The point is that when curling localhost:8080 it should give me back some authentication html, which it doesn't. The request just hangs. The log output I added was recorded while the request waited. So Jenkins doesn't even seem to notice something coming  in. Like I said. When reducing the instance type to m5.12xlarge, the same configuration works as it should.

Comment: strange! But, This is somthing I cannot reproduce since I do not have the set-up as urs. Still it amazes me that ur are trying to run jenkins in that instance :)